# How much CPU/RAM would I need to host 5 Ruby on Rails 3 applications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hosting

How much CPU/RAM would I need to host 5 Ruby on Rails 3 applications?

I am talking about applications that will not get more than 300 hits per day each.

Comment: That depends heavily on how what those apps are doing. A hello world app won't require much. Something that crawls though millions of DB rows and does very complex O(n^2) computations with the returned 5k rows would have vastly larger requirements.

Comment: I'm confused about the close votes citing *"not a real question".* I could see an argument for *off-topic* and migration to Server Fault, but programming fundamentally requires some capacity awareness so I can see an argument for leaving it here. But *"not a real question"* means that there isn't actually an answer, yet this question actually has a *numerical* answer. It's like asking *"what's the square root of...?",* questions just don't get any more objective than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's only a few hits per minute, even after allowing for peak hours and bursts.

It's hard for me to imagine a reasonably new machine that would have any problems with that.

But to answer your question, it depends a bit on which web server you choose but about 300 MB / Rails server is a starting point for planning a big application rollout. Since you won't be needing lots of simultaneous transactions, a couple of threads should do and therefore a totally random 2GB machine should be more than enough.

I wouldn't really bother deploying a server without at least 8 or 16 GB, though, even if not immediately needed. Given the other costs involved, even a small budget allocation for memory should result in way more than your scenario needs.